# Jquery mute only works on first page load

Tags: jquery, onclick, html5-video

I made this Jquery button for layerslider plugin. But the button only works when you load the page. When you browse the site and return to the hoempage the button doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestions?

```
function(element) {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.mute-video', function (){
        if (jQuery("video").prop('muted')) {
            jQuery("video").prop('muted', false);
            jQuery(this).addClass('unmute-video');

        } else {
            jQuery("video").prop('muted', true);
            jQuery(this).removeClass('unmute-video');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop  >
    <source src="/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/StarTransfer-promo-aanhanger.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

CSS:

```
.mute-video {
    background:url(http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/volume47.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size:42px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border:0 !important;
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    text-indent:-999px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.unmute-video {
    background:url(http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/volume47.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size:42px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border:0 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.unmute-video:focus,
.unmute-video:active {
    outline: none;
}

.mute-video:focus,
.mute-video:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will u share ur html?

Comment: where u r applying those css?

Comment: In the CSS form from layerslider

Comment: I also tried to place it in overruling child theme!

Answer (score 0):

The `.mute-video` button upon which you have added the `click` event does not seem to be the same after navigation.

It seems that some navigation or re-render of the page rewrites a new button.

Make sure your function gets called on every page render or navigation.